# Why is my images stretched when drawn on a SurfaceView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am manually creating a SurfaceView in code and setting it as content view on my activity like this:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
mainSurface = new MainSurface(getBaseContext());
mainSurface.getHolder().setFixedSize(width, height);
setContentView(mainSurface);
```

I then simply draw images like this on the canvas:

```
canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("imageName", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id);
canvas.drawBitmap(image, pos[0], pos[1], null);
surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

But things are strange... Some images/bitmaps are stretched and the positions work different from image to image so if I give two images the same position they are not placed the same place? It is like there are some layout management going on that I don't know off, but how can that be? Should they not be absolute positions always when drawing on a SurfaceView?

I am totally puzzled!

**EDIT**
Ok it was because I only have images in the "drawable" folder, if I copy them to the "drawable-hdpi" they are not stretched! So to turn my question in another direction, can I make Android stop doing that? Can I make Android just use my images as-is even though if they only exist in the "drawable" folder and at the same time use those images (like the icon and such) that are in the different dpi folders?

Comment: are you sure its not stretched before drawing? I cant see reason for it to stretch.

Comment: How would it be that? As you can see I just call decodeResource and then draw it at some position.

Comment: Ok I try and debug the image.getHeight() right after creation and it is stretched... But why?

Comment: Check your resource, in the resources folder, and ensure its not stretchd before you load it in. Because again, There is no reason for it to , from `decodeResource`. Try opening the image in paint, re-saving it, and then seeing if it still has the same problem.

Comment: It is not, none of the images are stretched no matter what image program I open them in! They are all placed in the "drawable" folder and not the "drawable-hdpi" folder if that makes a difference (I did try and copy them to the "drawable-hdpi" and it gives the same result).

Comment: Ok that IS the problem, I had forgotten to update eclipse so it did not know of the images in "drawable-hdpi" - i am updating my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I only have images in the "drawable" folder, if I copy them to the "drawable-hdpi" they are not stretched!

EDIT: In fact if you want to use the same images for all screens and not have them resized by Android, you can place them in a "drawable-nodpi" folder